# Java Process print output while running

Tags: java, linux, bash

I am trying to run `split` command in a Java program. When I run it in the console with argument `--verbose`, it prints the generated chunk as follows:

```
creating file 'chunk00'
creating file 'chunk01'
creating file 'chunk02'
```

But when I run it in a java program, these outputs will be printed after finishing the process. What I must do to get outputs while `split` process is running?

I've used the following code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("split", "-a 2", "-d", "-b 52MB","--verbose",path+"/"+db,"chunk");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        File workingFolder = new File("/home/hajibaba");
        pb.directory(workingFolder);
        Process proc = pb.start();
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

        // read the output from the command
        String s = null;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        proc.waitFor();
```

However, it works for a bash script that uses `echo` for print same results.

Comment: You must also split the "-a 2" to "-a", "2", also "-b 52MB" to "-b", "52MB"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I/O is line buffered in an interactive session but buffered when writing to a pipe.

To work around the problem you can turn off buffering with the `unbuffer` command.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("unbuffer", "split", "-a2", "-d", "-b52MB","--verbose",path+"/"+db,"chunk");
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe